# Different usage of methods returning Azure.Response<T>

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-storage

Both methods [CreateBlobContainerAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobserviceclient.createblobcontainerasync?view=azure-dotnet) and [GetPropertiesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.getpropertiesasync?view=azure-dotnet) return a Task<[`Response<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.response-1?view=azure-dotnet)>. Here's an example that uses them. It can easily be reproduced in a VS .NET 7 project that references package `Azure.Storage.Blobs`, version 12.14.1.

```
BlobContainerClient containerClient = await blobServiceClient.CreateBlobContainerAsync("container" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
Response<BlobContainerProperties> properties = await containerClient.GetPropertiesAsync();
```

`Azure.Resonse<T>` defines an [implicit operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.response-1.op_implicit?view=azure-dotnet). The first call in the example converts implicitly, and I would expect the same for the second call.

Why are the method usages different?

Comment: If you do `BlobContainerProperties properties = await containerClient.GetPropertiesAsync();` it would also conver it implicitly.

Comment: I feel dumb righ now. If you write as answer I'll accept, @NotFound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implicit conversions allow you to convert a type without having to perform a cast. It does however require your code to use it as the implicit type. In your example you could do so by changing the type of the variable it's saved in e.g.

```cs
BlobContainerProperties properties = await containerClient.GetPropertiesAsync();
```

Another example would be a method requiring a parameter of a certain type. If your class allows an implicit cast you don't have to perform the cast yourself.